# private_endpoint between two resource group services

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-container-registry

I have a container registry in azure which is implemented by `terraform` as you can see in the following code:

```
resource "azurerm_container_registry" "container_registry" {
  name                = replace("${var.name}${var.namespace}", "-", "")
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name

  sku = "Premium"

  public_network_access_enabled = false

  network_rule_set = [
    {
      default_action = "Deny"
      ip_rule = []
      virtual_network = [
        for subnet_id in var.allowed_subnets : {
          action    = "Allow"
          subnet_id = subnet_id
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

On the other side, I have a virtual machine with different resource groups. As I want to push created docker-images in the `VM` to the `registry` I want to have a private connection between these two. My `terraform` project is as below:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                = "${var.name}-${var.namespace}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name

  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.virtual_network.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.ContainerRegistry"]

  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = true
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role_assignment" {
  scope                = data.terraform_remote_state.container_registry.outputs.container_registry_id
  role_definition_name = "AcrPush"
  principal_id         = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.virtual_machine.identity[0].principal_id
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint" {
  name                = "${var.name}-${var.namespace}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "container-private-connection"
    subresource_names              = ["registry"] 
    private_connection_resource_id = data.terraform_remote_state.container_registry.outputs.container_registry_id
    is_manual_connection           = false

  }
}
```

I suppose with `private_endpoint` I can have a safe connection for `az acr login --name`  but it doesn't work and return 403. Could you please help me with this?

```
Unable to get AAD authorization tokens with message: An error occurred: CONNECTIVITY_REFRESH_TOKEN_ERROR
Access to registry 'tempregistry.azurecr.io' was denied. Response code: 403. Please try running 'az login' again to refresh permissions.
WARNING: Unable to get admin user credentials with message: The resource with name 'tempregistry' and type 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries' could not be found in subscription 'temp-dev'.
ERROR: Unable to authenticate using AAD or admin login credentials. Please specify both username and password in non-interactive mode
```

(I remove extra codes, like resource definition and vnet)

Comment: Hello! Done.@Ans

Comment: Thanks, Do you think creating a virtual private link with the DNS zone for container registry is a good idea?@AnsumanBal-MT

Comment: No just by `Run command` in Azure console! I don't want to have public IP.

Comment: It works but I don't wanna give admin access to it! Just I want to set acrPush role for VM and Pull access for another VM!

Comment: No you are not giving admin access you are creating username and password for the private acr to access . So when you give acr push role assigned to managed identity of vm it will search that username and password and login but it will have only push and pull permissions only. You can test for other operation as well which are permitted to acrowner role .. let me know if that answers your ask

Comment: That's great thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry! I think I made a mistake! It doesn't work with admin-enabled let me double-check it first.

Comment: Hey @AnsumanBal-MT ! `public_network_access_enabled` you enabled this, and I don't want public network access!

Comment: Hi @maryam Abdoli , you will have to enable it if you use run command . Otherwise remote login to the vm and then run the command . For a fully private environment .

Answer (score 0):

***I tried the code and I received the same error as you which is :***

```
Unable to get AAD authorization tokens with message: An error occurred: CONNECTIVITY_REFRESH_TOKEN_ERROR
Access to registry 'ansumanacrtest.azurecr.io' was denied. Response code: 403. Please try running 'az login' again to refresh permissions.
WARNING: Unable to get admin user credentials with message: The resource with name 'ansumanacrtest' and type 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries' could not be found in subscription 'xxxxx'.
ERROR: Unable to authenticate using AAD or admin login credentials. Please specify both username and password in non-interactive mode
```

To solve above error we have to ***give the managed identity of the VM `Reader` Role in the same resource group where the ACR is located*** to read the details of ACR and ***enable the admin in ACR*** to create a username and password.

But again when I tried the same operation from ***Run Command in Portal*** , It gave me ***login failed error*** as the ***IP is not allowed which the run command is using*** as below :

[image]

***So ,Once I got the IP that Portal is using then I added it in the network rule set in the below code which I used earlier to create the resources :***

```
resource "azurerm_container_registry" "container_registry" {
  name                = "ansumanacrtest"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku = "Premium"
  admin_enabled = true
  public_network_access_enabled = true # as we are running commands from Run Command Script , we have to allow selected public access
#network rule set can be added after you get the IP from portal Run Command
  network_rule_set { 
      default_action = "Deny"
      ip_rule = [{
          action = "Allow"
          ip_range = "20.127.31.73"## IP received from the above error 
      }]
  }
}
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role_assignment" {
  scope                = azurerm_container_registry.container_registry.id
  role_definition_name = "AcrPush"
  principal_id         = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.example.identity[0].principal_id
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "VMcontributor" {
  scope = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.example.identity[0].principal_id
}


resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint" {
  name                = "pe-ansumanacr"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name = "container-dns-group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = ["${azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id}"]
  }

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "container-private-connection"
    subresource_names              = ["registry"] 
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_container_registry.container_registry.id
    is_manual_connection           = false

  }
}
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "privatelink.azureacr.io"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

#private DNS Link
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "example" {
  name                  = "${azurerm_container_registry.container_registry.name}-dnslink"
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
  registration_enabled = false
}
```

**Output:**

[image]